# Display each mail body as it is in browser using PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'tnvishwas1@gmail.com';
    $password = '********** ';
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM "amithkv32@gmail.com"');
    foreach ($emails as $e){
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$e,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$e,1);
        echo $message 
    }
?>
```

When I tried to run the above code, it's showing like this:

> Year: 1996 Make: Mercury Model: Villager Drive: Automatic Engine: 3.6
>   - 6 Cylinders ----------------------------- Part: Transmission ----------------------------- Name: ABCD Phone: Text: No Email: ABCD@gmail.com Location:  xyz,123456 Notes: A good rebuilt
>   transmission

Below is the actual format I need and which is same in gmail:

> Year:   1996
>
> Make:   Mercury
>
> Model:  Villager
>
> Drive:  Automatic
>
> Engine: 3.6 - 6 Cylinders
>
> Part:   Transmission
>
> Name:   ABCD
>
> Phone:
>
> Text:  No
>
> Email: ABCD@gmail.com
>
> Location: xyz,123456
>
> Notes: A good rebuilt transmission

Comment: Note: a semi colon is missing after your last `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your mail body contains carriage return characters (`\n`). These won't be shown as such in a browser.

To cure this, the simplest thing to do is to change the `echo` command to:

```
echo $message.'<br/>'
```

This will insert a hard break after each row

Answer (score 0):

Use function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):
"Returns string with `'<br />'` or `'<br>'` inserted before all newlines (`\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` and `\r`)."

I.e. replace `echo $message` by `echo nl2br( $message )`.

Comment: thanx a lot , it work for me , but when i tried to save the content into database , its storing with the html tags , i don't need tat , as i am going to display it in text box in my application,it gonna display all message with html tags what to do .....?

Comment: For the textbox (`<textarea>` HTML tag?) you don't need this function. The line breaks will show automatically. Just use the function to view the database content (not in the form).

Comment: if i store $message in my DB table will it contain html tags or not ?,if no how i need to include html tags in tat ....

Comment: I would store it in the database without HTML Tags. So you could edit those mails without nasty HTML Tags in a textarea. But for displaying them as text use the function `nl2br`.